# woocommerce and php code for setting variable product stock status

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm kind of new to wordpress, woocommerce and PHP and I need your help to solve a long time headache problem.

I have 2 online stores that should share the same stock products.

I made a PHP code that runs every time an order is issued and writes on the server a stock.csv with the actual stock for each variable product. And another php code that reads the csv from the other online store (not on the same host server) and updates it's stock if the other store is lower for each variable product. It works fine when it needs to reduce stock according to the other store.

Sometimes I receive new stock and it takes a lot of time to update both stores, so I update only one of them and then run the same procedure of updating stock, but change the condition just to copy the same quantity from csv for each variable product based on name and variable code.

The following code is a small piece of the one that updates the stock, to copy exactly the quantity for each variable product:

K is the local store that needs to update it's stock to be the same as A store.
$kid is the post_id of every variable product

```
if($astock>0){
    update_post_meta( $kid, '_stock', $astock);
    update_post_meta( $kid, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    }
else{
    update_post_meta( $kid, '_stock', 0);
    update_post_meta( $kid, '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
    }       
$my_post = array('ID'           => $kid);
wp_update_post($my_post, $wp_error);
```

My problem is that the stock and stock status is updated well for every variable product, but the main product remains out of stock (I see this "out of stock" tag on the admin woocommerce Product editing page). I set woocommerce not to show out of stock products, so even it has variable products in stock (I checked in product edit interface), the main product doesn't show on the store page. I have to edit every product and just press Update (like updating a blog post). After this everything is ok.

Is there a php command to update the main product? So it turns itself to instock? The product is set to variable and it doesn't have any checkbox ticked for managing stock or stock status on the General tab, just in Variances tab.

Thank you very much!
Best regards!

Comment: You need to use in your code [**`wc_delete_product_transients( $product_id );`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_delete_product_transients.html) function may be, as some product data is cached in transcients or you can also clear all products transcients in WooCommerce settings > System status > Tools…

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I'm afraid it doesn't do the job. I tried programmatically and also went to woocommerce system status Tools and deleted transients manually. Nothing happened.